# javascript Hide/show div on checkbox: checked/unchecked

Tags: javascript, css, checkbox

I am trying to make a function in javascript, that will hide / show particular div in my registration form, depending on the state of my checkbox (checked or not). 
Here is my function:

```
 function doruc() {
    var elem = document.getElementById('powermail_fieldwrap_331');
        if (document.getElementById  ('powermail_field_doruovaciaadresa2_1').checked) {
        elem.display='block';
        } else {elem.display:none;}
}
```

It isnt working. I am checking and unchecking my checkbox, but nothing happens. Oh and one more thing. I want that div to be initialized as hidden. Should I put in my css this? :

```
 #powermail_fieldwrap_331{
 display:none;
 }
```

I would highly appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use

```
var elem = document.getElementById('powermail_fieldwrap_331');
document.getElementById('powermail_field_doruovaciaadresa2_1').onchange = function() {
    elem.style.display = this.checked ? 'block' : 'none';
};
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/xSvLc/1/)

---

If you want to hide it by default, you could use `#powermail_fieldwrap_331{display:none;}`. But if you want to be sure, better use

```
var elem = document.getElementById('powermail_fieldwrap_331'),
    checkBox = document.getElementById('powermail_field_doruovaciaadresa2_1');
checkBox.checked = false;
checkBox.onchange = function doruc() {
    elem.style.display = this.checked ? 'block' : 'none';
};
checkBox.onchange();
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/xSvLc/2/)

Comment: Thank you. It works. Could you please explain it to me? What was wrong on my function and so on?

Comment: @user2886091 You code didn't work because you should have used `elem.style.display='block'` instead of `elem.display='block'`, and `elem.style.display='none'` instead of `elem.display:none`. Moreover, you need to run that code each time the checkbox is changed, so you need to listen to `change` event (assuming you weren't using `checkBox.onchange = doruc` in your code)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
elem.style.display='block'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write it like this :

```
function doruc() {
var elem = document.getElementById('powermail_fieldwrap_331');
    if (document.getElementById ('powermail_field_doruovaciaadresa2_1').checked) {
    elem.style.display='block';
    } else {elem.style.display='none';}}
```

and regarding your second question, you can either write in the div tag `style="display:none"` or you can do as you said (add a class for the element).

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in using display: none; to hide your DIV initially.

As for your checkbox, try removing the spaces between getELementById and ('powermail_field...

Also you need to change:

```
} else {elem.display:none;}
```

to:

```
} else {elem.display = 'none';}
```