# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'checked' of null

Tags: javascript

I am using a Javascript at [javascript Hide/show div on checkbox: checked/unchecked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19734907/javascript-hide-show-div-on-checkbox-checked-unchecked/19734954#19734954).

```
var elem = document.getElementById('powermail_fieldwrap_331'),
    checkBox = document.getElementById('powermail_field_doruovaciaadresa2_1');
checkBox.checked = false;
checkBox.onchange = function doruc() {
    elem.style.display = this.checked ? 'block' : 'none';
};
checkBox.onchange();
```

I changed "checkBox.checked = false;" to "checkBox.checked = true;"
It works anyway but produces an error:
**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'checked' of null**

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xSvLc/323/)

In this case, how I fix this error?

Thanks.

Comment: That means that `document.getElementById` isnt' finding an element with that ID.

Comment: I guess, your javascript code is executing before the DOM elements are ready on the page. May be,you need to execute the code that is trying to get the inputs after the DOM is ready.

Comment: It seems to be working fine in the fiddle.

Comment: @Peter, thanks. But, I don't see any error in fiddler..

Comment: @Vimalan. Yes, no errors in Fiddle. But when it's in actual environment, IE or Chrome presents the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'checked' of null." If I change "true" to "false", no error.

Comment: @Barmer. Thanks for your comment. It works fine in Fiddle. But when it's in actual environment, IE or Chrome presents the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'checked' of null." If I change "true" to "false", no error.

Comment: @Peter Then, there must be something different in your code. Take a look again that it's exactly the same.

Comment: jsfiddle wraps all code in an onload event. that's why it works fine there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fiddle works fine. The only issue can be that the script is executed before the checkbox was part of the DOM.

Either wrap your code within an `onload` event.

```
window.onload = function() {
    var elem = document.getElementById('powermail_fieldwrap_331'),
    checkBox = document.getElementById('powermail_field_doruovaciaadresa2_1');
    checkBox.checked = false;
    checkBox.onchange = function doruc() {
        elem.style.display = this.checked ? 'block' : 'none';
    };
    checkBox.onchange();
};
```

Or make sure that the script tag is written after the checkbox is part of your DOM:

```
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="powermail_field_doruovaciaadresa2_1" checked="checked" />
    Show/hide
</label>
<div id="powermail_fieldwrap_331">Lorem ipsum</div>

<script>
var elem = document.getElementById('powermail_fieldwrap_331'),
    checkBox = document.getElementById('powermail_field_doruovaciaadresa2_1');
    checkBox.checked = true;
    checkBox.onchange = function() {
        elem.style.display = this.checked ? 'block' : 'none';
    };
    checkBox.onchange();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code executes, before the document is fully ready, which is causing you to receive the ID as null, since it is not rendered yet.

It is a common problem, this is why in jquery you always use `$(document).ready();`

To make sure, that the document is fully loaded first and no elements will be executed before the document is fully loaded, preventing errors like this.

There is a very helpful post regarding this in java script:

[Pure java script jquery ready](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899372/pure-javascript-equivalent-to-jquerys-ready-how-to-call-a-function-when-the)

Comment: Can I move "checkBox.checked = true;" to behind "checkBox.onchange = function()":  (http://jsfiddle.net/xSvLc/325/ )
Now it produces no error in my environment. I wonder if it's correct in jQuery grammar.

Answer (score 1):

Your document.getElementById("checkboxid")   contains null value. For that store it in  a variable and then you can check like

```
  var checkbox = document.getElementById("chkteam");
        if (checkbox == true) {

         // your condition 
        }
```

Then  It will Work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change all of  tag without checked
by