# HTML Table which contains check boxes, Need to Export HTML Table to Excel File for only the checked rows?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, export-to-excel

I had an HTML table in which one column is a checkbox. We can select any of the rows in that particular table. Now I need to export only the rows which are checked from the HTML table to excel file. How can I do it?

In the below Image i want to Export only the 1,2 and 5 rows which are checked to excel file.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part allows you to get the data of the row in which the data has been selected

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="here"></div>
  <table style="width:100%" id="table">
  <tr>
    <td><input class="checkMe" type="checkbox" />    &nbsp;   </td>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>4350</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input class="checkMe" type="checkbox" />    &nbsp;   </td>
    <td>Mark</td>
    <td>Kllis</td> 
    <td>5110</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input class="checkMe" type="checkbox" />    &nbsp;   </td>
    <td>Keath</td>
    <td>Marks</td> 
    <td>53210</td>
  </tr>
    </table>
  <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>

  <script>
    function myFunction(){
      var checks = document.getElementsByClassName('checkMe');
      var table = document.getElementById('table')

      var element = document.getElementById("here");
      while (element.firstChild) {
        element.removeChild(element.firstChild);
      }
      for (var i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
        if(checks.item(i).checked == true){
          var fName = table.rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML; //first column  
          var lName = table.rows[i].cells[2].innerHTML; //first column  
          var num = table.rows[i].cells[3].innerHTML; //first column  
          var para = document.createElement("p");
          var node = document.createTextNode(fName + " " + lName + " "  + num);
          para.appendChild(node);

          element.appendChild(para); 
        }
      }
    }
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

For writing into to CSV there is already a great answer [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333537/how-to-generate-excel-through-javascript) and he made a cool code on fiddle which you can take a look at [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/5KRf6/3/)

Comment: Glad it helps bud

Comment: Hey Mr. Fabulous here i am not hard coding the table rows.I am generating those rows through javascript. and i am getting one error i.e., Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'checked' of undefined.. and the code is  if(checks[i].checked == true).Why it is showing error i am not able to find.

Comment: Cannot really say from a top of my head because I cannot see the code, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31634528/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-set-property-checked-of-null) thread discussed exactly that